# Create time-series visualizations in Grafana from Loki logs

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

I am trying to create time-series graph for Falco metrics. Falco metrics are exposed as log lines, picked up by loki and are available as log line is to query in Grafana. Now I want to create time-series dashboards to monitor Falco resource usage over time.
Here is the Loki logql query I am using:
`{container="falco"} |= "Falco metrics snapshot" | json | line_format "{{.output_fields_falco_cpu_usage_perc | float64 }}"`

Here is a sample Falco log line:

```
{
   "hostname": "falco-66fvm",
   "output": "Falco metrics snapshot",
   "output_fields": {
       "evt.source": "syscall",
       "evt.time": 1706197973772413400,
       "falco.cpu_usage_perc": 1.5,
       "falco.duration_sec": 5821,
       "falco.evts_rate_sec": 4547.282760121657,
       "falco.host_boot_ts": 1706191785000000000,
       "falco.host_num_cpus": 4,
       "falco.hostname": "falco-66fvm",
       "falco.kernel_release": "6.5.0-10-generic",
       "falco.memory_pss": 72,
       "falco.memory_rss": 72,
       "falco.memory_vsz": 1063,
       "falco.num_evts": 14613961,
       "falco.num_evts_prev": 14340981,
       "falco.outputs_queue_num_drops": 0,
       "falco.start_ts": 1706192152631996200,
       "falco.version": "0.36.2",
       "scap.engine_name": "bpf",
       "scap.evts_drop_rate_sec": 0,
       "scap.evts_rate_sec": 4584.163425485088,
       "scap.n_drops": 0,
       "scap.n_drops_perc": 0,
       "scap.n_drops_prev": 0,
       "scap.n_evts": 14751370,
       "scap.n_evts_prev": 14476176
   },
   "priority": "Informational",
   "rule": "Falco internal: metrics snapshot",
   "source": "internal",
   "time": "2024-01-25T15:52:53.772413451Z"
}
```

When I try the same query to build grafana time-series dashboard, it shows data missing number field. I did try transformations, but it did not give any results.

Comment: Typo? `.output_fields_falco_cpu_usage_perc` => `.output_fields.falco_cpu_usage_perc` there should be `.` after `.output_fields`

Comment: @zori, no, loki's json expression [automatically sanitises output field names](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/query/log_queries/#parser-expression).

Answer (score 0):

You need `unwrap` function, e.g.

```
{container="falco"} 
|= "Falco metrics snapshot" 
| json
| unwrap output_fields_falco_cpu_usage_perc
```

This is not copy&paste solution. I don't have yoru data, so I can't verify it - fix any syntax or other issues in the example query of course.

Comment: If I understand [this](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/query/metric_queries/#unwrapped-range-aggregations) correctly, unwrapped expression must be used inside of `rate` or one of the `_over_time` functions.

Comment: I guess `avg_over_time` is a function of choice for this case.